# How to consume but not capture some chars, in PetitParser?

Tags: parsing, dart, petitparser

I defined a rule:

```
def("invokation", char('@').word().plus().flatten());
```

For "@who", it will match and get `@who` as result.

How to ask it just return `who` without `@`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if your question is about PetitParser for [Java](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserJava) or [Dart](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart)?

In any case, you need to connect `char('@')` and `word().plus().flatten()` to a sequence. Then you pick the second element of the list resulting list, ignoring the first character.

In Java this looks like this:

```dart
def("invokation", character('@')
    .seq(word().plus().flatten())
    .map(Functions.nthOfList(1));
```

And in Dart this is:

```dart
def("invokation", char('@')
    .seq(word().plus().flatten())
    .pick(1));
```

Btw, I just committed an improvement to PetitParser for Java so that you can use `pick(int)` in Java too.

Comment: Can we add an api such as "drop()" which means some matcher should consume the input but will drop the result? So the code can be: `def("invokation", char('@').drop().seq(word().plus().flatten())`

Comment: This is certainly doable, but IMHO leads to all kind of weird situations. For example, in the above `seq(...)` the single word would still be wrapped into a list. In general composability would suffer a big deal. That said, there is nothing that prevents you form introducing a drop other new composition operators.